# Copy one string into another, skipping all characters that are not alphabet letters

Tags: c++

This code is supposed to verify if my input string is a palindrome or not. It is working just fine, but it has to ignore non-alphabet characters. I tried to change my `scanf()` to `scanf("%[a-z, A-Z]", s)`, but it's stopping when it finds a non-alphabet character:

input: asd12dsa

output: asd

it was supposed to be : asddsa

So I tried to copy my string, excluding all non-alphabet characters.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong, please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s[100], mirr[100];
    int i, n;
    char d[100];

    scanf("%s", s);

    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0' ; i++)
        {
        if ((s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') || (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z'))
            {
            d[i]=s[i];
            }
        }
    printf("%s", d);

    //printf("%s\n", d);
    strcpy(mirr,d);
    strrev(mirr);
    if(strcmp(mirr,d)==0)
        printf("The word is polindrom");
    else
        printf("The word is not polindrom");
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [isalpha](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/)

Comment: You tagged this question [tag:c] originally, which cannot be, since `#include<iostream>` won't ever work for plain c code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ -- but that and `using namespace std;` are just cargo-cult code, since the code doesn't actually use anything from the C++ standard library.

Comment: `if ((s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') || (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z'))` -- This will not work on systems that are not ASCII.  It will also not work on systems that are ASCII, but do not use English as the locale and have other alphabetic characters.  As pointed out, always use `std::isalpha`, since the system knows what an alphabetic character is.

Answer (score 0):

When you skip characters then `s[i]` is not necessarily placed at `d[i]`. For example once you skipped a character then `d[i]` needs to get `s[i+1]`. This is simpler if you keep track of the index seperately. Or rather use `std::string`, and `std::isalpha`. To reverse a string you can use `std::reverse` or construct a new string by calling its constructor with reverse iterators. In total your code looks very much like C not like C++. At the least you should use the C++ versions of the headers when you compile it as C++ (ie `<cstdlib>` and `<cstdio>` instead of `<stdlib.h>` and `<stdio.h>`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{  
   std::string input;
   
   std::string output;
   
   std::cin >> input;

   for (size_t i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i) {
       if (std::isalpha(input[i])) output += input[i];
    }
    
    std::cout << output;
    
    std::string rev{output.rbegin(),output.rend()};
    
    if(rev == output)
        std::cout << "The word is polindrom";
    else
        std::cout << "The word is not polindrom";
}
```

Comment: Yes, I wanted it to be more like C because I'm not familiar with c++. 
I'm also getting an error on line 19 [Error] in C++98 'rev' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'

Comment: @XpYcTaJIb C and C++ are two different languages.  If you want to code in `C`, then you should code in `C`.  If you want to code in C++, use C++.  You shouldn't be straggling the fence -- commit to writing C++ code, or write `C` code, but tag your original question as `C`.

Comment: @XpYcTaJIb `#include<iostream>` and `using namespace std;` are clearly not C. You must compile your code as C++ because it is not C code. C++ and C are largly compatible, but they are two different languages. If you want to write C code then you should use a C compiler. C++98 can be considered ancient. The current standard is C++17 (or C++20). Try to update your compiler (or decide to write C)